# Prevent user tapping other controls in a view while it is loading

Tags: uibutton, iphone-sdk-4.1

In my application i have a Home page - It has 3 buttons each button will invoke a another view, that view will have a data comes from a web services. When i press a first button it took a time to get data from web services and to show that view. In that time if i press another buttons that actions is invoked and that view is showed up. how to avoid the tapping of other controls when the (first button is clicked) view is loading. plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Till the view loads:

```
anotherButton.userInteractionDisabled = YES;
```

Then, after loading make it NO.